# Hide and show menu after clicked on it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have just started my study with css and html and I have first problem. I try to show my menu after clicked on it. When I clicked on it, menu item' s show up and immediately hide. How can I show it and hide after next click on my menu? 
There is demo: jsfiddle.net/jekfej46/1/ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?  It's hard for us to help, without seeing what you've done...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `:active` is only a state. When you click an element, it changes the state to `:active` but *only as you keep holding it*. The best way to do it would be using jQuery to add a class to the menu when you click that button.

If you don't know how to use jQuery, there are lots of tutorials all over the internet that can easily guide you through. It's pretty easy once you get the principles.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jekfej46/1/

In this case, JavaScript checks if the element already has the `active` class. If it does, the class is removed so the menu closes. But you can change that behaviour if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the click event only with CSS. You need JavaScript  here. Something like this will do this for you using jQuery.

```
$('#category').on('click', function(){
    $('.dropdown-content').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, a lot guys. Now, I know that I also need js and jQ to improve my pages. Thanks.